# Promoted to frontpage teasers in a block

Tags: blocks, theming

**General:**

I am new with Drupal; so, I was trying to add new regions to Zen (sub)template, but got very confused why contents of my new-created region "content 2" appears on page **above** the original so called "promoted to front page teasers", which I considered to be a "content"...

Now, it seems "promoted teasers" are not in a block - and that's why they are not in a "content region"?

If so, How to put "promoted teasers" in a block?

Also confusing - what do "main page content" block? - It seems I cannot disable it and if I put "main page content" in a "content" region - my new "content 2" region appears above the "promoted teasers" ; if I put this "main page content" block in "content 2" - both content of "content 2" and "promoted teasers" appear next each other in the same row (?!)....

May be it depends somehow on CSS also?

I don't know, I just somehow assumed that "promoted teasers" are "content" region's content, but it's not - so, what should I do with it now?

**Ingredients used**:

Drupal 7.30

Zen 7.x.5.x

Display Suite

Views

few others...

```
<div id="main">

    <div id="content" class="column" role="main">
      <?php print render($page['highlighted']); ?>
      <?php print $breadcrumb; ?>
      <a id="main-content"></a>
      <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
      <?php if ($title): ?>
        <h1 class="page__title title" id="page-title"><?php print $title; ?></h1>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
      <?php print $messages; ?>
      <?php print render($tabs); ?>
      <?php print render($page['help']); ?>
      <?php if ($action_links): ?>
        <ul class="action-links"><?php print render($action_links); ?></ul>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php print render($page['content']); ?>
      <?php print $feed_icons; ?>

    <?php
    // content - 2 region , my own added
      print render($page['content2']); ?>
     <?php print render($page['content3']); ?>
     <?php print render($page['content4']); ?>
     <?php print render($page['content5']); ?>
      </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use Views:

- Create view of content
- Create "Block" display
- Use filters to only show ones with "promoted to frontpage" selected
- In Format section set  Show: Content | Teaser
- Put your block on the frontpage

That's all.

Comment: Yes, it's kind of an answer; but - what to do with existing teasers, since they appear outside of regions or they still in some region?

Comment: My question is not so much about Blocks, but about Regions - How the "promoted teasers" appear on my page, when they are not in any Region?

Comment: @user1981528 they are hard-coded in Drupal core. Historical reasons, mostly. See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/1122/16495

Answer (score 0):

What I finally found and did:

In page.tpl.php

```
<?php if ($title): ?>
        <h1 class="page__title title" id="page-title"><?php //print $title; ?></h1>
```

--->  Commented out the Headline/ page title **//print $title**

Next: the lines:

```
<?php print render($page['content']); ?>
```

I changed to :

```
<?php
      if (!drupal_is_front_page()){
  print render($page['content']);} ?>
```

// Before I found this I also unchecked "promoted" , but I think anyway, this removes all that default staff; and also I added earlier several additional 'content 2n' regions, so I don't mind missing that on front page.